# Firefox starts playing new audio streams in wrong device

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Here is how default pulseaudio settings look after I removed all config files and restarted PA:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H26OP.png)

Should I try and [unmute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCy0l.png) Built-in Audio Analog Stereo (I have to choose "Headphones" for sound to appear, even though they are marked as "unplugged" and speakers are not), I have the sound for exactly one song in Firefox, and when another starts, Firefox changes to playing in HDMI: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL5Xe.png)

I disabled HDMI in config and then it all became just fine (that is being said, pulseaudio doesn't really have to choose from any sound devices because there is only one.. don't think this is intended behaviour). But then I needed to create some new sound devices (for my RNNoise microphone noise cancelling) and again the problem came back (this time Firefox always plays sound in "Null Output"), configuration looking like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL08w.png). I find it rather strange that I have two devices selected simultaneously. Auto-Mute is [disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUOF6.png). How can I set my sweet Built-in Audio Analog Stereo to being default, and moreover, why something marked as "unplugged" plays sound and something that is not marked doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo alsactl restore` seemed to do the trick, although I had to select "speakers" and not "headphones (unplugged)" and also it must be done every time on boot.

Answer (score 1):

You can control which apps pipe audio streams to which output devices using `pavucontrol` (PulseAudio Volume Control (`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`)).

I was having a similar issue where my system sound was outputting to my Bluetooth device, as selected in `gnome-settings`, but Firefox was outputting to my built-in speakers. When I opened `pavucontrol`, I found that the outputsetting for Firefox under Playback > Applications was different from the output setting for my system sounds. I'm not sure how the setting got this way, but I suspect that it's due to too many apps with conflicting settings options (e.g., `gnome-settings`, `pavucontrol`, and `blueman`), so I purged `blueman`. I'll reboot and see if the default setting issue persists, but I think setting the output device for apps individually in PulseAudio Volume Control effectively solves this issue.